# SQL Image Extraction

Tags: sql, image, image-processing, extract, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract images from a restored database. The script below ostensibly runs fine: meaning it extracts the images and saves the number of files I expect to see (and the size I would expect to see) into a network folder as .pdf files. However, when I try to open the files this is the error message I receive:

*Adobe Reader could not open 'filename.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file 
has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).*

1. I have run this script before in other environments (2 to be exact) and it's worked fine.
2. I have verified that the actual images are good. You can access the files via the front end.
3. It doesn't appear that the values are encrypted. Although I'm not completely sure.
4. The Data Type natively is: image
5. I've been using SQL for a while but would consider myself a noob, whereas, I'm basically self-taught -so please go easy.

Any guidance / suggestions / insight will be very much welcome.

Thank you.

```
--========================================================================

USE <<ENTER_DATABASENAME>>
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
DECLARE @FILEID VARCHAR(12),
@IMAGE VARBINARY(MAX),
@OBJSTREAM INT, 
@FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX),
@BASEDIR VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @BASEDIR = '<<ENTER_NETWORKPATH>>'
PRINT 'BASEDIR: ' + @BASEDIR
DECLARE IMGEXTRACT CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
select <<ENTER_COLUMNNAME01>>, <<ENTER_COLUMNNAME02>> 
from <<ENTER_TABLENAME>>

OPEN IMGEXTRACT
FETCH NEXT FROM IMGEXTRACT INTO @FILEID, @IMAGE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @FILENAME = @BASEDIR + '\' + @FILEID + '.pdf'
PRINT @FILENAME
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @OBJSTREAM OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @OBJSTREAM, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJSTREAM, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJSTREAM, 'Write', NULL, @IMAGE
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJSTREAM, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FILENAME, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJSTREAM, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @OBJSTREAM
FETCH NEXT FROM IMGEXTRACT INTO @FILEID, @IMAGE
END
CLOSE IMGEXTRACT
DEALLOCATE IMGEXTRACT
GO

--========================================================================
```

Comment: this answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900442/exporting-an-image-column-to-a-pdf-file-in-sql-server

Comment: vkp -thank you for the link!  As stated, all my SQL is self-taught. I'm stuck at the bcp line and not exactly sure where to go from there. Can you explain to me how this works in your script?