# export files (pdf etc) from MS SQL image data type to filesystem

Tags: sql, sql-server, file-io, export

I want to export Data, several filetypes, .jpg, .pdf, .msg, .doc, etc into Windows filesystem.

The data is unfortunately stored in a `image` data type column.

[image]

[image]

After exporting it gives me an error "file corrupted or filetype not supported, e.g not correct decoded".

I tried to export with an c# 20line script, and with that sql script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127325/1650038
but both unsuccessful.

[image]

Any ideas how to export the files? **Doesn't matter with what technology, c#, sql etc** . New location will be an oracle DB..

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900442/exporting-an-image-column-to-a-pdf-file-in-sql-server

Comment: no success with any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I don't now the reason but BCP is not working fine with exporting files and images.
The Best Way to export files from SQL is to Create a DotNet application, Loading them in a DataSet and Export them to files . There a lot of articles showing how to do it.

- [Example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10861/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-usin)
- [Example 2](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103960-save-and-retrieve-images-with-sql-server/)

But for TSQL :

Try the solution writen in this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file)

And for additional information read this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192018/export-images-from-a-sql-server-using-stored-procedures/40194919#40194919) and read the comments at the bottom of the correct answer. We have made a lot of workarounds.