# Exporting Image column (varbinary) to Excel File in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have tried lots of different solution methods but none of them has solved my problem yet. I just want to run a query and export the result containing the FileData (image) field to an Excel file. I also tried to use some external add ons, but not succeeded.

Please note that I do not want to export image files, instead want to obtain image data on the exported Excel file.

***Update :*** I have a table called FileAttachments and assume that there is 2 columns : Id, FileData (image column). So, I retrieve the result simply this query:

```
SELECT * FROM FileAttachments
```

And then I obtain the FileData fields as string of the image.

Comment: Why close instead of help? :(

Comment: Do you want the data as a string in a column in the Excel sheet? For example like it displays when you run a query on a varbinary field in management studio: `0xABC1234....` ?

Comment: I already get the string in excel, but I want photo of it in the excel column.

Comment: Maybe this question can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776611/insert-picture-into-excel-cell

Comment: Take a look at the last macro, maybe you can tailor it to your purpose?

Comment: this [`question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900442/exporting-an-image-column-to-a-pdf-file-in-sql-server) may help.

Comment: Please post code you tried

Comment: @mortb The answer is not related to my problem.

Comment: @vkp It might help, but I do not understand where I use these commands, etc. Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov I added the SQL query, but I do not think that it was needed.

Comment: @ClintEastwood please post full query, which outputs .xls file, not a resultset. How you create Excel file?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov My query does not create an excel file, maybe that is the missing point I have. Any example please?

Comment: This is example how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086880/t-sql-export-to-new-excel-file

Comment: @MikhailLobanov Will it also export varbinary column and display as image on Excel field?